# Paypal Integration on Java web applicaton

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, paypal

Currently, I am successful in making the first call to the 
https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp
which brings me back the `TOKEN` and `ACK` which is of course successful... now the problem is how to capture the values from these variables. I couldn't think a way. Can somebody help me getting these values in my `servlet` so that i could compare and manipulate other steps for online payment !

Thanks in advance !

This is the form i send to https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp

```
<input type="text" name="USER" value="rspunk07-facilitator_api1.hotmail.com" /><br/>
<input type="text" name="PWD" value="1402570771" /><br/>
<input type="text" name="SIGNATURE" value="AOgUKQLphsryE4s2aIWzkssJyVf3ALKhcP5TZ2W4CnDz.bAbL.WoCv9q" /><br/>
<input type="text" name="METHOD" value="SetExpressCheckout" /><br/>
<input type="text" name="VERSION" value="98" /><br/>
<input type="text" name="PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT" value="10" /><br/>
<input type="text" name="PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE" value="USD" /><br/>
<input type="text" name="PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION" value="SALE" /><br/>
<input type="text" name="cancelUrl" value="http://localhost:8084/E-Drivers_Licensing_System/onlinepayment.jsp" /><br/>
<input type="text" name="returnUrl" value="http://localhost:8084/E-Drivers_Licensing_System/success.jsp" /><br/>

<input type="submit" name="h" value="Register"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="reset" name="cancel" value="Cancel"/><br/>
```

In response to this, i get `TOKEN=EC%2d08371303KU3173044&TIMESTAMP=2014%2d06%2d17T10%3a32%3a09Z&CORRELATIONID=26d5a8792d431&ACK=Success&VERSION=98&BUILD=11457922` in the same url https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp

[image: This is how it looks !]

Now, the problem i have is, to capture the details provided in the url from my servlet

```
public class OnlinePaymentController extends HttpServlet {

protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    try {




    } finally {            
        out.close();
    }
}
```

How do i do that ?

Answer (score 1):

```
// This method is called by the servlet container to process a GET request.
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
    doGetOrPost(req, resp);
}

// This method is called by the servlet container to process a POST request.
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
    doGetOrPost(req, resp);
}

// This method handles both GET and POST requests.
private void doGetOrPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
    // Get the value of a request parameter; the name is case-sensitive
    String name = "param";
    String value = req.getParameter(name);
    if (value == null) {
        // The request parameter 'param' was not present in the query string
        // e.g. http://hostname.com?a=b
    } else if ("".equals(value)) {
        // The request parameter 'param' was present in the query string but has no value
        // e.g. http://hostname.com?param=&a=b
    }

    // The following generates a page showing all the request parameters
    PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
    resp.setContentType("text/plain");

    // Get the values of all request parameters
    Enumeration enum = req.getParameterNames();
    for (; enum.hasMoreElements(); ) {
        // Get the name of the request parameter
        name = (String)enum.nextElement();
        out.println(name);

        // Get the value of the request parameter
        value = req.getParameter(name);

        // If the request parameter can appear more than once in the query string, get all values
        String[] values = req.getParameterValues(name);

        for (int i=0; i<values.length; i++) {
            out.println("    "+values[i]);
        }
    }
    out.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is, you don't really want to redirect the user to Paypal since the paypal API response is not designed to be passed back directly to the user.

Instead your Servlet needs to act as a client so the flow would be the following:

- User fills out form and submits
- Form is submitted to *your Servlet* rather than the API directly
- Your Servlet makes a request to the API using a Java HTTP client such as http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/
- Your Servlet parses and decodes the response from the paypal API
- You Servlet forwards to a jsp representing the next step in the payment process.

Presumably all you want is the token which you can then pass back to the client to be written as a hidden field and submitted in the next step.

I'm not very familiar with the PayPal APIs but I would recommend exploring their documentation further to make sure this is the best way to access their services.